# How to create source bundle?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

To deploy the app, we use:

```
eb deploy --label version_label
```

but how would I just create the source bundle without actually deploying it?

I know that we can just zip the entire director of app, but I want to still apply the ignored files and directories in the `.ebignore` file